# C# Read from SslStream continuously (long connection, last for up to days) and Efficiently without infinite loop

Tags: c#, sockets, ssl, sslstream

I am completely new to C#, and need to encrypt the data sent and received between client and server, after googled it for two days, learnt the best way is to use SslStream, some answers I found give good examples but they all somehow assume we just need to read one message and then close the connection, which is totally not my case, I have to read whenever a user triggers his device to send a message through the persistent connection.
one example from Microsoft documentation:

```
static string ReadMessage(SslStream sslStream)
    {
        // Read the  message sent by the client.
        // The client signals the end of the message using the
        // "<EOF>" marker.
        byte [] buffer = new byte[2048];
        StringBuilder messageData = new StringBuilder();
        int bytes = -1;
        do
        {
            // Read the client's test message.
            bytes = sslStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            // Use Decoder class to convert from bytes to UTF8
            // in case a character spans two buffers.
            Decoder decoder = Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();
            char[] chars = new char[decoder.GetCharCount(buffer,0,bytes)];
            decoder.GetChars(buffer, 0, bytes, chars,0);
            messageData.Append (chars);
            // Check for EOF or an empty message. <------   In my case,I don't have EOF
            if (messageData.ToString().IndexOf("<EOF>") != -1)
            {
                break;
            }
        } while (bytes !=0);

        return messageData.ToString();
    }
```

and other answers actually tell me how to continuously read from a SslStream, but they are using infinite loop to do it, on the server side, there could be thousands clients connected to it, so the possible poor performance concerns me,like this one :
[Read SslStream continuously in C# Web MVC 5 project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32820779/7994967)

So I want to know if there is a better way to continuously read from a persistent SslStream connection.

I know with bare socket I can use **SocketAsyncEventArgs** to know when there is new data ready, I hope I could do this with SslStream, probably I misunderstand something, any ideas would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: How SSLStream works https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security.sslstream?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: The easy answer is to keep the infinite loop, but use `await ReadAsync(...`. While the method is paused & waiting for I/O, no thread will be executing.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman That's the right answer. I did saw `ReadAsync` when I was searching for answers, but I misunderstood it would immediately return zero when there's no data in the buffer. It actually only return zero when the connection being closed. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my shot at it. Instead of looping forever, I chose recursion. This method will return *immediately* but will fire an event when `EOF` is hit and continue to keep reading:

```
public static void ReadFromSSLStreamAsync(
    SslStream sslStream,
    Action<string> result,
    Action<Exception> error,
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = null)
{
    const string EOFToken = "<EOF>";

    stringBuilder = stringBuilder ?? new StringBuilder();
    var buffer = new byte[4096];

    try
    {
        sslStream.BeginRead(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, asyncResult =>
        {
            // Read all bytes avaliable from stream and then
            // add them to string builder
            {
                int bytesRead;
                try
                {
                    bytesRead = sslStream.EndRead(asyncResult);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    error?.Invoke(ex);
                    return;
                }

                // Use Decoder class to convert from bytes to
                // UTF8 in case a character spans two buffers.
                var decoder = Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();
                var buf = new char[decoder.GetCharCount(buffer, 0, bytesRead)];
                decoder.GetChars(buffer, 0, bytesRead, buf, 0);
                stringBuilder.Append(buf);
            }

            // Find the EOFToken, if found copy all data before the token
            // and send it to event, then remove it from string builder
            {
                int tokenIndex;
                while((tokenIndex = stringBuilder.ToString().IndexOf(EOFToken)) != -1)
                {
                    var buf = new char[tokenIndex];
                    stringBuilder.CopyTo(0, buf, 0, tokenIndex);
                    result?.Invoke(new string(buf));
                    stringBuilder.Remove(0, tokenIndex + EOFToken.Length);
                }
            }

            // Continue reading...
            ReadFromSSLStreamAsync(sslStream, result, error, stringBuilder);
        }, null);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        error?.Invoke(ex);
    }
}
```

You could call it as so:

```
ReadFromSSLStreamAsync(sslStream, sslData =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Finished: {sslData}");
}, error =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Errored: {error}");
});
```

It's not `TaskAsync`, so you don't have to `await` on it. But it is asynchronous so your thread can go on to do other things.

Comment: Great pattern for reading from SslStream, but still missed some of my point, I need to read continuously from the stream, or say there are endless messages sequentially coming from a client at any time, every one of them ends with a _<EOF>_ . But I think just a little change to your code would make it works fine: simply move this line `ReadUntilEOFAsync(sslStream, result, error, stringBuilder);` out of _else_curly brace，it will keep reading more messages.

Comment: @QiuZhou -- added that in. It will now continue to read after `<EOF>` is found instead of stopping.

Comment: @QiuZhou -- keep in mind there could be a condition where a buffer reads in two or more `<EOF>` tokens in one pass. I added in code for that condition as well.

Comment: @QiuZhou -- Also, the `ToString().IndexOf()` may be a bottleneck. You may consider doing something a little more optimized, like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12261971/1204153 or just scrap `StringBuilder` and use `Span<T>` to make it really fast

Answer (score 0):

Consider checking out the following [asnwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73373619/10721627). `SSLStream` was derived from the `Stream` class therefore the `ReadAsnyc` method can be used. Code below, read until the `<EOF>` delimiter characters then return with the received message as `string`.

```
    internal static readonly byte[] EOF = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("<EOF>");

    internal static async Task<string> ReadToEOFAsync(Stream stream)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            long eofLength = EOF.LongLength;
            byte[] messageTail = new byte[eofLength];
            while (!messageTail.SequenceEqual(EOF))
            {
                int bytesRead = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                await memoryStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

                Array.Copy(memoryStream.GetBuffer(), memoryStream.Length - eofLength, messageTail, 0, eofLength);
            }

            // Truncate the EOF tail from the data stream
            byte[] result = new byte[memoryStream.Length - eofLength];
            Array.Copy(memoryStream.GetBuffer(), 0, result, 0, result.LongLength);

            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result);
        }
    }
```

The received messages was appended to the `memoryStream`. The first `Array.Copy` copies the message tail from the buffer. If the message tail is euqals to the `<EOF>` then it stops reading from the stream. Second copy is to ensure truncating the delimiter characters from the message.

**Note**: There is a more sophisticated way of slicing using [Span](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.span-1?view=net-6.0) introduced in .NET Core 2.1.