# How to read continuously and asynchronously from network stream using abstract stream?

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, .net-standard-2.0, networkstream

##### Description

I would like to read asynchronously from a `NetworkStream` or `SSLStream` using their abstract `Stream` parent class. There are different ways to read asynchronously from stream:

- Asynchronous Programming Model (APM): It uses `BeginRead` and `EndRead` operations.
- Task Parallel Library (TPL): It uses `Task` and creates task continuations.
- Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP): Operations are suffixed *Async* and `async` and `await` keyword can be used.

I am mostly interested using the **TAP** pattern to achieve asynchronous read operation. Code below, asynchronously read to the end of stream and returns with the data as byte array:

```
    internal async Task<byte[]> ReadToEndAsync(Stream stream)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            int bytesRead = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            while (bytesRead != 0)
            {
                // Received datas were aggregated to a memory stream.
                await memoryStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                bytesRead = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }

            return memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

The buffer size is 4096kB. If the transferred data is more than the buffer size then it continues to read until 0 (zero), the end of the stream. It works with `FileStream` but it hangs indefinitely at the `ReadAsync` operation using `NetworkStream` or `SslStream`. These two stream behave differently than other streams.

The problem lies behind that the network stream `ReadAsync` will only return with 0 (zero) when the `Socket` communication is closed. However I do **not** want to close the communication every time a data is transferred through the network.

##### Question

How can I avoid the blocking call of the `ReadAsync` without closing the `Socket` communication?

Comment: If the socket is open but no data is available, you'd expect the `ReadAsync` of a stream representing a connection to that socket to hang indefinitely until either, data arrives, the socket is closed or cancellation is triggered.

Using `... await ReadAsync(...)` Blocks only the waiting task, allowing other tasks to continue processing.

Comment: That is right. But I need the result of the current received data. Therefore I have also await ReadToEndAsync method which results with blocking.

Comment: Consider creating a mesh with TPL Dataflow, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library. However, you can't both wait till the end and start processing before the end. You will need concurrent tasks with intermediate buffering.

Comment: @Jodrell Thank you for pointing out the DataFlow programming model. It turns out, it can be used with the async and await operators https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-implement-a-producer-consumer-dataflow-pattern

Comment: The TPL Dataflow types are specifically designed for working with TAP async/await. They can save you from writing some risky pipework. My point wasn't about the applicability of Dataflow but rather a need to adjust your perspective a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an issue similar to yours, I want to read from a network stream that might send packets at random intervals. I am receiving length-prefixed packets, that is, the packets begin with a byte (e.g., 20) which represents how many bytes I need to read from the network stream to get the rest of the packet.

After my testing, I have had many issues with prior solution I've tried, such as the payloads being truncated, part of the payload missing, super intensive CPU usage, no payload at all, or exceptions being thrown, clients randomly disconnecting immediately, or what appears to be a deadlock or just waiting forever.

Starting with .NET 7, there are two very interesting and useful methods:

- ReadAtLeastAsync
- ReadExactlyAsync

In my limited testing, they have been very, very reliable and I haven't had any issues, even with sending data at random intervals. The client/server can send data with delays, and it just `awaits` perfectly. I have attached an example below showing how these can be used, including a fake flaky network situation where these methods handle it perfectly.

There is a *lot* of machinery for these methods if you look at their source.

### ReadAtLeastAsync

Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.readatleastasync?view=net-8.0

`n` is a hard-coded number that you supply. It represents the number of bytes to read, at least. Don't set this to zero, because it'll just spin.

- This is guaranteed to read `n` bytes into your buffer if `throwOnEndOfStream` is set to true because you'll get an exception if it can't do this. It will wait until the stream has sent at least `n` bytes, and then give you a buffer with those bytes.
- This is not guaranteed to read `n` bytes into your buffer if `throwOnEndOfStream` is false. Instead, you have to check the return value. If it is zero, then the client closed the connection. If it is not zero, then truncate the buffer up to the return value, and then call `ReadAtLeastAsync` again forever until it is not zero.

### ReadExactlyAsync

Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.readexactlyasync?view=net-8.0

This reads exactly `n` bytes into your buffer. If it can't do this, then it'll throw an exception. It will wait on the stream until it has received `n` bytes, then will continue.

Paste this entire code block into a new project (e.g., `Program.cs`) and then run it (look at `Main()` for the different examples):

```
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public static class Logger
    {
        public static void LogWithTime(string message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"[{DateTime.Now}]: {message}");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This class is not super important, because it will be on the server's side.
    /// This simulates the server sending packets whenever they want to, and might
    /// delay many seconds between sending each packet at random times.
    ///
    /// The server sends messages as message length prefixed payloads. The payload contains
    /// the message, in UTF-8, as bytes.
    /// Messages have a maximum size of 255 bytes in this example.
    /// </summary>
    public static class TcpServerExample1
    {
        public static async Task SendMessages()
        {
            Logger.LogWithTime("Server: starting server...");
            var client = new TcpClient();
            await client.ConnectAsync(IPAddress.Loopback, 8000);
            Logger.LogWithTime("Server: connected to client");

            await using (var networkStream = client.GetStream())
            await using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(networkStream))
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    // send a message to client
                    var message = $"Hello #{i}!";
                    var messageAsBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
                    // messageAsBytes = [72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 87, 111, 114, 108, 100, 33]

                    var messageLengthPrefix = new[] { (byte)messageAsBytes.Length };
                    // messagePrefix = [12]

                    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
                    writer.Write(messageLengthPrefix);
                    Logger.LogWithTime($"Server: wrote message prefix for message #{i}");

                    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
                    writer.Write(messageAsBytes);
                    Logger.LogWithTime($"Server: wrote message payload for message #{i}");
                }
            }

            client.Close();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is us. We listen to the server, who sends us packets.
    /// </summary>
    public static class TcpClientExample1
    {
        public static async Task StartListening()
        {
            var listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Loopback, 8000);
            listener.Start();

            var client = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
            await using var networkStream = client.GetStream();

            while (true)
            {
                // again, assume that maximum message length is 255 bytes
                var msgLengthBuffer = new byte[1];
                await networkStream.ReadExactlyAsync(msgLengthBuffer);

                var msgPayloadBuffer = new byte[msgLengthBuffer[0]];
                await networkStream.ReadExactlyAsync(msgPayloadBuffer);

                Logger.LogWithTime($"Client: received message '{Encoding.UTF8.GetString(msgPayloadBuffer)}'");
            }

            // remember to close the connection; in this example, we assume that we read forever
            //client.Close();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Here, the server is passively reading messages, while the client actively sends them
    /// </summary>
    public static class TcpServerExample2
    {
        public static async Task StartListening()
        {
            Logger.LogWithTime("Server: starting server...");
            var client = new TcpClient();
            await client.ConnectAsync(IPAddress.Loopback, 8000);
            Logger.LogWithTime("Server: connected to client");

            await using (var networkStream = client.GetStream())
            {
                var messageLength = new byte[1];
                await networkStream.ReadExactlyAsync(messageLength);

                var messagePayload = new byte[messageLength[0]];
                await networkStream.ReadExactlyAsync(messagePayload);

                Logger.LogWithTime($"Server: received '{Encoding.UTF8.GetString(messagePayload)}'");
            }

            client.Close();
        }
    }

    public static class TcpClientExample2
    {
        public static async Task SendMessages()
        {
            Logger.LogWithTime("Client: starting client...");
            var client = new TcpClient();
            await client.ConnectAsync(IPAddress.Loopback, 8000);
            Logger.LogWithTime("Client: connected to server");

            await using (var networkStream = client.GetStream())
            await using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(networkStream))
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    // send a message to client
                    var message = $"Hello #{i}!";
                    var messageAsBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
                    // messageAsBytes = [72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 87, 111, 114, 108, 100, 33]

                    var messageLengthPrefix = new[] { (byte)messageAsBytes.Length };
                    // messagePrefix = [12]

                    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
                    writer.Write(messageLengthPrefix);
                    Logger.LogWithTime($"Server: wrote message prefix for message #{i}");

                    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
                    writer.Write(messageAsBytes);
                    Logger.LogWithTime($"Server: wrote message payload for message #{i}");
                }
            }

            client.Close();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Here, the server is passively reading messages, while the client actively sends them
    /// </summary>
    public static class TcpServerExample3
    {
        public static async Task StartListening()
        {
            Logger.LogWithTime("Server: starting server...");
            var client = new TcpClient();
            await client.ConnectAsync(IPAddress.Loopback, 8000);
            Logger.LogWithTime("Server: connected to client");

            await using (var networkStream = client.GetStream())
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    var buffer = new byte[8]; // doesn't have to be eight
                    var minBytesToRead = 1;
                    var numReadBytes = await networkStream.ReadAtLeastAsync(buffer, minBytesToRead, false);
                    if (numReadBytes == 0)
                    {
                        // this occurs when the client intentionally closes the connection
                        // the payload from the client may be smaller than our buffer we allocated for it,
                        // depending on how the packets arrive and their frequency, or if the server is done,
                        // so make sure to only take the first {numReadBytes} from the buffer
                        Logger.LogWithTime("Client closed connection");
                        break;
                    }

                    Logger.LogWithTime($"Server: received [{string.Join(", ", buffer[..numReadBytes])}]");
                }
            }

            client.Close();
        }
    }

    public static class TcpClientExample3
    {
        public static async Task SendMessages()
        {
            Logger.LogWithTime("Client: starting client...");
            var listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Loopback, 8000);
            listener.Start();

            var client = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
            await using var networkStream = client.GetStream();

            Logger.LogWithTime("Client: connected to server");
            await using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(networkStream))
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++)
                {
                    // random payloads of length 1 to 10
                    var randomPayload = Enumerable.Repeat(0, Random.Shared.Next(1, 20)).Select(_ => (byte)Random.Shared.Next(0, byte.MaxValue)).ToArray();

                    writer.Write(randomPayload);

                    Logger.LogWithTime($"Client: sent [{string.Join(", ", randomPayload)}]");

                    // simulate slow network
                    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Random.Shared.Next(0, 5000)));
                }
            }

            client.Close();
        }
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            // passively connecting (listening), actively sending
            //await Example1();

            // actively connecting, passively listening
            //await Example2();

            // download something from the server that might arrive in
            // packets delayed by random amounts of time
        }

        private static async Task Example1()
        {
            // client is us
            var client = TcpClientExample1.StartListening();
            var server = TcpServerExample1.SendMessages();

            await Task.WhenAll(client, server);
        }

        private static async Task Example2()
        {
            var client = TcpClientExample2.SendMessages();
            var server = TcpServerExample2.StartListening();

            await Task.WhenAll(client, server);
        }

        private static async Task Example3()
        {
            var server = TcpServerExample3.StartListening();
            var client = TcpClientExample3.SendMessages();
            
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
            await Task.WhenAll(client, server);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for the answer. I was unaware of the `ReadExactlyAsync` and the `ReadAtLeastAsync` methods. Could you provide links for them so that we can navigate to the docs faster?

Comment: @PéterSzilvási Sounds reasonable - I've updated my answer

Answer (score 3):

> I would like to read asynchronously from a NetworkStream or SSLStream using their abstract Stream parent class.

Do you really *need* to? TCP/IP socket communication is quite complex to do correctly. I *strongly* recommend self-hosting an HTTP API or something like that instead.

> The problem lies behind that the network stream ReadAsync will only return with 0 (zero) when the Socket communication is closed.

Yes, and the code you posted only returns a result when the entire stream has been read.

So, what you need is a different return condition. Specifically, you need to know when a single *message* has been read from the stream. What you need is [message framing](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/message-framing.html), as described on my blog.

I also have some [sample code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/sample-code-length-prefix-message.html) on my blog showing one of the simplest message framing solutions (length prefix). Take careful note of the complexity and length of the *simplest* solution, and consider whether you really want to write socket-level code.

If you do want to continue writing socket applications, I recommend watching my [YouTube series on asynchronous TCP/IP socket programming](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLIebvSMVr_dehKSoq6vuAW0BGEM6QnDlS).

Comment: Yes, we implemented a TCP/IP socket from the ground up, hence we can not switch to HTTP easily. Thank you for the youtube video link, I wish I had come across these video sooner. I will definitely check it out.

Answer (score 0):

As Stephen Cleary blog post pointed out there are two approaches used for [message framing](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/message-framing.html): length prefixing and delimiters.

- **Length prefixing**: Message length was known, because it was sent through the network.
- **Delimiters**: Message length was unknown. Escaping was determined by the delimiter characters.

Codes below use length prefixing in order to prepend the message length to the message.

```
internal async Task SendAsync(Stream stream, byte[] message)
{
    byte[] messageSize = BitConverter.GetBytes(message.Length);
    await stream.WriteAsync(messageSize, 0, messageSize.Length).ConfigureAwait(false);
    await stream.WriteAsync(message, 0, message.Length).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

The sender side first converts the message length to a byte array and then sends it to the receiver. The `messageSize.Length` is 4 because a signed 32-bit integer was converted. After that, the client sends the actual message. The receiver side is a little bit more complicated:

```
internal async Task<byte[]> ReceiveAsync(Stream stream)
{
    byte[] messageBuffer = null;
    byte[] lengthBuffer = new byte[4];

    try
    {
        await stream.ReadAsync(lengthBuffer, 0, lengthBuffer.Length).ConfigureAwait(false);
        int messageLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(lengthBuffer, 0);

        messageBuffer = new byte[messageLength];
        await ReadToEndAsync(stream, messageBuffer, messageLength).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // Error occured during receiving.
        throw;
    }

    return dataBuffer;
}
```

First the receiver reads the message length to a byte array with length 4. Then it converts the received byte array to a signed `Int32` value. Once the message length is known then the message can be read until the end.

```
private async Task ReadToEndAsync(Stream stream, byte[] messageBuffer, int messageLength)
{
    int offset = 0;
    while (offset < messageLength)
    {
        int bytesRead = await stream.ReadAsync(messageBuffer, offset, messageLength).ConfigureAwait(false);
        if (bytesRead == 0)
        {
            // Socket is closed.
            break;
        }

        offset += bytesRead;
    }
}
```

It reads the message from the stream until the `messageLength` is reached. If single read operation is not enough then it advances the buffer's offset with the amount of bytes read from the stream.

Note considering to prevent DOS attack:

> Whether using length-prefixing or delimiters, one must include code to prevent denial of service attacks. Length-prefixed readers can be given a huge message size; delimiting readers can be given a huge amount of data without delimiters.

Comment: The code above doesn't properly handle the situation where two messages are read at once.

Comment: @StephenCleary That is right. The answer was changed from delimiter to length prefixing approach.

Comment: The code is still wrong. The `ReadAsync` used to read the length prefix can return any number between 0 and 4 (inclusive), and that return value is currently ignored instead of being handled correctly.

Comment: Is this problem only could be handled using PipeLines?

Comment: No, but pipelines definitely make it easier.

Comment: I believe the last code snippet should be instead `stream.ReadAsync(messageBuffer, offset, messageLength - offset)`

Comment: @alexyorke Looking at the [ReadAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.readasync?view=net-8.0) documentation, the third parameter is the **maximum** number of bytes from a stream. I assume that if I have a bigger message length than expected, it will read less than or equal to that message length.

Comment: @PéterSzilvási I just posted my answer, I'm hoping I'm solving the same problem as you and the OP. The third parameter is the total bytes relative to the offset, so every `n+1`th iteration of the loop will be larger than the buffer; I was getting an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` otherwise. You can take a look at "example 4" to make sure I'm understanding the problem correctly: https://gist.github.com/alexyorke/264a1c08ff5fe8f10e97ddfe3142288f

Comment: Oops - you are the OP :)